# USB2.0 device not recognized anymore

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

I have a Ubuntu 10.10 (x86) system which I use to test GNU Radio applications. I have successfully been using a USRP1 with a USB2.0 connection for some time now, yet at some point yesterday it appears to have stopped working.

- With `lsusb` I don't even see the device listed anymore. I tried multiple ports with no luck.
- A USB1.0 mouse seems to work fine.
- Windows XP seems to recognize the device (no driver, but I see the device ID)
- USRP works fine on my Fedora machine
- tried different cables and another USRP

This is a rather old laptop, so part of me thinks the hardware may just be dying. However, Windows still at least recognizes the USRP, so I am hopeing maybe a driver install will fix the problem.

So, a USB mouse works fine, but somehow my USB2.0 based USRP stopped working. How can I debug this problem? Can I somehow reinstall the USB2.0 drivers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was a UDEV issue. The USRP could only be used as root by default, the following will create UDEV rules for a normal user.

```
sudo addgroup usrp
sudo usermod -G usrp -a <YOUR_USERNAME>
echo 'ACTION=="add", BUS=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="fffe", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0002", GROUP:="usrp", MODE:="0660"' > tmpfile
sudo chown root.root tmpfile
sudo mv tmpfile /etc/udev/rules.d/10-usrp.rules
```

From gnuradio.org:

> Ubuntu uses udev for handling hotplug devices, and does not by default provide non-root access to the USRP.

I tried reloading the rules, but I had to reboot in order for everything to work.

Comment: This was annoying because we had another user account for testing before, but then I created a new account (for other reasons) and forgot to add it to the UDEV rules.

Answer (score 0):

If lsusb does not see it, I **don't** think it's a UDEV issue.  I think Ubuntu just really doesn't see it at the very lowest-level of the USB Handshake.  This normally means a hardware issue.  Since you've checked the cables and port and since it does work it Windows, I would guess a power issue.  Try using a powered USB hub in-between the radio and the host.

Comment: But how come `sudo lsusb` showed the device? Doesn't that point to permission issues with UDEV? If you ask me it doesn't make sense anyway. Even if a normal user doesn't have permissions to use a device, they should still be able to tell if it is connected to the system.

Comment: @Mr. If `sudo lsusb` sees the device, it's probably not hardware related.  As a test you can try `sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/bus/usb` and see if it shows up in lsusb normally and if it starts working.  The permissions will reset after next boot.  If it is a permissions problem then we can look at fixing the udev rules.